# Database Design: Use mapping tables or include data directly in tables

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am writing a project management web app just for practice. The basic idea is that a user can add a project to the app and then manage their tasks and appointments related to the project through the interface. I'm currently designing the Database and I was wondering what best practice would dictate here.

I have 4 tables so far:

```
+----------+   +-------------+   +--------------+   +-------------+
|Users     |   |Projects     |   |Tasks         |   |Appointments |
+----------+   +-------------+   +--------------+   +-------------+
|id        |   |id           |   |id            |   |id           |
|username  |   |project_name |   |task_name     |   |appt_name    |
|fname     |   |project_desc |   |task_details  |   |appt_details |
|sname     |   |             |   |task_deadline |   |appt_date    |
+----------+   +-------------+   +--------------+   +-------------+
```

I'm taking the basic relationships as:

- one `user` can have many `projects`,`tasks`, and `appointments`.
- one `project` can have many `users`, `tasks` and `appointments`.
- one `task` can have many `users`, but only be associated with one `project`. A `task` can't be associated with an `appointment`.
- The rules for the `tasks` also apply to the `appointments`.

My question is: when is it suitable to use mapping tables and when is it suitable to include the data directly in the associated table? My take on my example would be:

- have a mapping table for each of users-projects/tasks/appts because there can be many users for each type and many of each type per user
- in the tasks and appointments tables include a `project_id` field that can be used to associate tasks and appointments with projects and thereby the users of that project.

Would this be the correct approach or is there a better solution? I'm fairly new to database design so I would really appreciate some constructive criticism

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *I'm currently designing the Database and I was wondering what best practice would dictate here*

Best Practice dictates that the data must be modelled, as data, without regard to the use or the app. Without regard to the platform as well, but the world is upside-down and backwards these days, the platform is chosen first.

Modelling means that you identify and consider the entities first, before you consider what you are going to do with them second (such as "mapping").

#### No Option

> > *My question is: when is it suitable to use mapping tables*

It is the normal method.

- Correct
- theoretically founded
- allows all functions and capabilities that users expect databases to have

  - eg. aggregation, single or multiple item (subset of the list) searches are very fast, etc
- easy to expand
- prevents preventable errors
- gives you chips that you can cash in, in Heaven.

> > *and when is it suitable to include the data directly in the associated table?*

Never.  That will create a comma-separated list in a single column.

- Incorrect
- No theoretical basis
- breaks First Normal Form
- beloved of the incompetent (they not only don't know the rules, they don't know when they are breaking the few rules they *do* know)
- database features and functions cannot be used

  - eg. searching for, determining if, a specific user is working on a project will cause a tablescan
- result is not a database, it is a Record Filing System
- difficult to expand
- you will spend half your life fixing preventable errors, and the other half thinking about how to replace it without letting anyone noticing
- guarantees you a specific place in hell, sixth level, with the frauds and those who cheat workers out of their wages, one level below murders, one above pædophiles and war-mongers

> > *have a mapping table for each of users-projects/tasks/appts because there can be many users for each type and many of each type per user*

Generally, yes.  But that is not clear.  "Type" rings alrm bells, it sounds like you intend to have one table that asupports all possibilities; nullable Foreign Keys; etc.  Refer "Never" above.

There should be an **Associative Table** (not "mapping") between only those pairs of tables that need it, not between each and every possibility.  And each such table relates ("links", "maps", "connects") just one discrete pair.

This will be resolved when the Normalisation is completed, next ...

#### Consideration

The requirement does sound a bit suspicious.  I do not accept that those tables are all isolated, fragmentary facts.  Consider:

- First, Tasks are probably a child of Project (you've implied that, such a dependency should be explicit).  Likewise, Appointments should be a child of Project.  As in, a Tasks cannot exist, except in the context of a Project.  Likewise for Appointment.
- Then you have to evaluate whether Users should be related to Projects (as given in the requirement).  It seems to me that an User is assigned to a Task (and thus related to the Project because the Tasks belongs to one Project), and not to all Tasks in the Project.  Likewise for User::Appointment.
- if Users are related to Projects (and not to specific Tasks), as per the requirement, it does seem too general.  Especially if an Appointment applies a Project, and therefore to all Users assigned to the Project.
- So it appears to me on the info received thus far, plus my suggestions (which have not been confirmed, so this one is thin ice), that Appointments are made at the lower level, the Task level, and may well apply to all Users assigned to the Task.
- There may be a *second type* of Appointment, at the Project level, which applies to the distinct set of all Users assigned to all Tasks in the Project.
- As long as my suggestions above are correct, particularly that Users are assigned to Tasks, if an Appointment is made at the Task level, it applies to all Users assigned to that Task, then there are no Associative ("mapping") Tables at all.
- IDs cannot provide row uniqueness.  How do you ensure row uniqueness, as demanded for relational databases ?

As you can see, stamping an ID column on every table that is perceived in the first draft of the model cripples, prevents, the data modelling exercise.  You need 10 to 12 drafts.  Somewhere around the fifth, you will assign Keys.  At 9 or 10, you will assign IDs to the few tables (if any) that need them.

Assigning IDs first guarantees a first draft implementation in an RFS, which means no database integrity, no database capability.

Consider, confirm/dent, discuss, etc.

Here's a diagram to use as a discussion platform.  Please use the link at the bottom of it, and familiarise yourself with the Notation, to whatever level you see fit.

[Project Management ERD • Second Draft](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/adohertyd%20ERD.pdf)

Comment: Another incredibly detailed answer with a lot to consider. Many thanks for taking the time to write all of that and to produce the ERD. I note that you have asked quite a few questions of me in your answer but I have changed my approach to this completely so it would result in a redundant conversation. Your points however have given me quite a lot to consider in future application design and I will refer to this answer many times I think

Comment: @adohertyd.  It is my pleasure, and thank you for the kind words.  If you are interested, go to my profile page, lists all my Answers, and read any that you find of interest for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion may not sound like a technical one, more like grammar. When describing your entities and their relationships with each other, do *not* mention or even think about tables, columns or whatever. At the beginning of the design process, they are entities -- not tables, attributes -- not columns. Don't influence the physical design too early.

*Do* use words that closely match the relationships. For example, I doubt the in the normal course of conversation, one user will ask another if they "have a relationship" with a project. It will be more like "Are you involved in this project?" or "Are you working on this project?" So a user can be *involved* in many projects and a project can have many users *involved* in it. Be specific in naming just what the relationship is but you don't have to get anal about it. There could be several close fits -- choose one and go on.

As for mapping tables, when you describe a many-to-many relationship, you don't really have much choice.

You do have a choice in a one-to-many relationship. A task, for example, is "performed for" only one project. This means that the FK to Project can be part of the Task tuple. But you can also implement a one-to-many mapping table. This is generally done when there seems to be at least a possibility that the relationship might evolve into a many-to-many sometime in the future.

The difference between a many-to-many and a one-to-many mapping table is trivial:

```
create table UserProjectMap(
    int    UserID  not null,
    int    ProjectID not null,
    constraint FK_UserProject_User foreign key( UserID )
        references Users( ID ),
    constraint FK_UserProject_Project foreign key( ProjectID )
        references Projects( ID ),
    constraint PK_UserProjectMap primary key( UserID, ProjectID )
);

create table TaskProjectMap(
    int     TaskID not null,
    int     ProjectID not null,
    constraint FK_TaskProject_Task foreign key( TaskID )
        references Tasks( ID ),
    constraint FK_TaskProject_Project foreign key( ProjectID )
        references Projects( ID ),
    constraint PK_TaskProjectMap primary key( TaskID )
);
```

In case you missed it, it's the last line of each definition.

Converting a one-to-many mapping table to many-to-many is easy -- just drop the unique constraint on one side. Or, in the example above, redefine the PK to include both FK fields. That means no structural changes, which are extremely difficult to do when a design has been in use for any length of time -- unless you've prepared for them ahead of time.

But that's 500-level work.

Oh, one more piece of advice. Don't be too quick to denormalize or make any changes for no better reason than it will make queries or DML easier for the developers. The sole purpose of the database (and your goal as the designer) is to serve the needs of the users, not the db developers. At the top of that list of needs is data integrity. Don't sacrifice data integrity for a little more performance or for ease of maintenance. The DBAs may grumble, but the users will appreciate it -- and it's the users who ultimately pay your salary.

Comment: That was a very informative and comprehensive response. Thanks for taking the time to write it I've a lot to take away from that